# Logistic Map Plotting Issues

Tags: matlab, ode, nonlinear-functions

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm trying to plot the logistic map x = λx(1-x) for λ in [0,4] and the initial condition from [0,1]. But for some reason I keep getting a really weird plot.

[image: Weird plot]

I don't think it's supposed to be like this. Could it be that my code is wrong?

Any help will do, thanks!

My code:

```
startL = 0; # The starting value of lambda
finalL = 4; # The final value of lambda
N = 1000; # The number of values of lambda points
          # between starting value and final value
          # of lambda. (optional)


L = linspace(startL,finalL,N); # A row vector of N lambda
                               #  points between startL and finalL.
M = 1000; # The number of iterations

 # Loop trough the values of lambda
 for k = 1:length(L)

   # allocate memory for x
   x = zeros(1,M+1);
   x(1) = 0.3; # Initial condition: x_0, from [0,1].

   results = zeros(1,M+1);
   # Iteration scheme for current lamda
   for m = 1:M
      x(m+1) = L(k)*x(m)*(1 - x(m));
      results(k,m) = x(m+1);
  end;
end;

plot(L, results, 'b.');
xlabel('\lambda');
ylabel('x_n');
title('Logistic Map');
```

Comment: You are plotting `results`, which is a 2D matrix as if it was a 1D vector. The fix proposed by @ben_Heo definitely works and makes a cool plot, but is this the way you meant to plot this?

Answer (score 2):

```
results=zeros(1, M+1);
```

is initialized for each k values in for loop

initialize it before for loop will work:

```
 results = zeros(N, M+1);
 for k = 1:length(L)

   % allocate memory for x
   x = zeros(1,M+1);
   x(1) = 0.3; % Initial condition: x_0, from [0,1].


   % Iteration scheme for current lambda
   for m = 1:M
      x(m+1) = L(k)*x(m)*(1 - x(m));
      results(k,m) = x(m+1);
   end;
end
```